# Window function, order by clause, between operator

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-order-by, window-functions

Consider the MWE below

```
WITH samp AS (
    SELECT '2023-01-01' AS day, 1 AS spent UNION ALL
    SELECT '2023-01-02' AS day, 2 AS spent UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2023-01-03' AS day, 3 AS spent
) 
SELECT day, 
       spent 
     , ARRAY_AGG(spent) OVER(ORDER BY day BETWEEN '2023-01-02' AND '2023-01-03') ss
FROM samp 
ORDER BY day
```

I cannot figure out what the order by clause is doing here. I'd expect to restrict the entries to those of the selected dates, but dates outside it also have a contribution? E.g., outcome of the above

| day | spent | ss |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '2023-01-01' | 1 | [1] |
| '2023-01-02' | 2 | [1,2,3] |
| '2023-01-03' | 3 | [1,2,3] |

Comment: It depends on what you're attempting to do.  Provide and expected output accordingly or check Tim's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clause

```
day between '2023-01-02' and '2023-01-03'
```

is a *boolean expression*, and will only evaluate to two possible values, true or false (1 or 0).  Therefore, your window function `array_agg(spent)` will compute using an order where dates other than 2023-01-02 and 2023-01-03 will be ordered first, followed by these dates next.

Here is your updated output showing the ordering logic:

```
     day         spent         ss      order (day between ...)
'2023-01-01'       1           [1]       0
'2023-01-02'       2         [1,2,3]     1
'2023-01-03'       3         [1,2,3]     1
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification Tim. Got it, then the cumsum default function of the order by clause applies to give different outcomes in the first row.